# Get each images in body in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom PHP scope in my Wordpress theme, like this:

```
foreach ($myprojects as $post){
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $output .= '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">';
        $output .= '<div class="portfolio-item">';

        if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
            $thumb          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
            $large_image    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
            $content        = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);


            $output .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$thumb[0].'" title="" alt="">';
        }else{
            $output .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/work_1.jpg" title="" alt="">';
        }

        $post_id = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $post_name = CFS()->get('project_name', '');

        $output .= '<a class="overlay" rel="shadowbox" href="'.$large_image[0].'">';
        $output .= '<p class="btn-preview">'.$post_id.'</p>';
        $output .= '</a>';

        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        $count++;
        $index++;
    }
```

Yes, it works fine. When I click `a` tag, open `$large_image` via prettyPhoto.
But this code for single image. I want to thumbnails stay same, but when click to link, open that multiple image via prettyPhoto. So, imported 2 images in post body and want to show these images.

In a nutshell, this code:

```
$large_image    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
```

Must be like this:

```
$large_image    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $body($post->ID), 'full');
```

But I know, this is not correct code. Its pseudo.

How can I fix my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your lightbox solution to fancyBox, use `data-fancybox-group` and a bit of Wordpress/PHP knowledge... that's it!

```
foreach ($myprojects as $post){
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $output .= '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">';
        $output .= '<div class="portfolio-item">';

        if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
            $thumb          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
            $large_image    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
            $content        = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);


            $output .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$thumb[0].'" title="" alt="">';
        }else{
            $output .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/work_1.jpg" title="" alt="">';
        }

        $post_id = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $post_name = CFS()->get('project_name', '');

        $output .= '<a class="overlay test fancybox" data-fancybox-group="'.$post->ID.'" href="'.$large_image[0].'">';
        $output .= '<p class="btn-preview">'.$post_id.'</p>';
        $output .= '</a>';

        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        $attached_images = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
        foreach($attached_images as $image){
        $large_attached_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'full');
        if($large_image[0] != $large_attached_image[0]){
        $output .= '<a class="overlay test fancybox" data-fancybox-group="'.$post->ID.'" style="display:none" href="'.$large_attached_image[0].'"></a>';
        }
        }

        $count++;
        $index++;
    }
```